# how to draw java uml class diagram with enum being created within another class

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Say I have a class name A. Within this class I define enum B by `public enum B {AA,BB,CC}`. Now I want to draw a uml to reflect this relation ship, how should I do this?

Comment: warning anyway in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797531/how-to-represent-the-nested-class-of-c-in-uml the beginning of the accepted answer is not anymore valid, look at all answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a class class diagram the representation uses `(+)----`, for instance :

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I just would like to confirm is this for java? I just saw this answer, sorry, but I found you said this for c++

Comment: @Rui whatever Java or C++ or any other programming language here, it is UML notation

Comment: This question might be stupid, but do you mean uml format is same for java and c++ right?

Comment: UML is language agnostic.

Comment: because UML is a norm with its own rules, it does not care about the programming languages

Comment: To be more precise I should have said "UML is _programming_ language agnostic". UML is (the L abbreviates it) a language itself.