# UML Class-Diagram. Declaring a class under a class

Tags: c#, uml, class-diagram

how would you declare this in a class diagram?

```
enum ErrorTitleType;

public class Users
{
    #region Custom Exception
    public class UsersException : Exception
    {
        public ErrorTitleType TitleTypeError { get; set; }
        public UsersException(string message, ErrorTitleType Typ ) : base(message)
        {
            TitleTypeError = Typ;
        }

    }
}
```

UPDATE: i was trying to have a customize Exception class for each logical class to seperate the errors with the UI class. Thats why i have 'Users' which is the locgial and 'UserException' to identify that its the exception class for error handling for 'Users'. i hope im not confusing anyone

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Generalization/Inheritance

Comment: In this example UsersException class inherited from Exception class as usual, what do you want to do? If you want to draw uml diagram look figure 4 on: https://developer.ibm.com/articles/the-class-diagram/

Comment: OP is trying to ask the relation between `Users` and `UsersException`

Comment: you can check out this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146519/private-nested-java-class-in-uml-diagram

Comment: i was trying to have a customize Exception class for each logical class to seperate the errors with the UI class. Thats why i have 'Users' which is the locgial and 'UserException' to identify that its the exception class for error handling for 'Users'. i hope im not confusing anyone.

Answer (score 2):

> Declaring a class under a class

There is a dedicated notation in UML to indicate a class (here *UsersException*) is nested into an other (here *Users*) :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you have coded is a nested class in UML as well. The class `Users` **owns** the class `UsersException`

In your model you would have something like

- Package Model

  - Class Users

    - Class UsersException

In a diagram you can use the nesting connector to indicate the fact that the class `Users` owns the class `UsersException`, or you could enlarge the class `Users` and place the class `UsersException` in there
[image]

PS. Usually we name classes singular => `User` and `UserException` instead of `Users` and `UsersException`.